# Twitter Bootstrap sorting icon alignment issues in table headers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout issue that I'm trying to solve that involves sortable columns. When a user is on a low resolution screen, or resizes their browser, the sorting icons dont line up with each other anymore. Users have complained many times about this.

In the following screengrab I'd like the sorting icons to line up with the green line rather than the way they are now (red line)

[image]

Here'e the jsfiddle snippet that renders the above table: http://jsfiddle.net/JgSMq/

```
 <table class="table table-bordered data-table sort display">
   <thead>
     <th class="sorting">ID Column <i class="sort-icon"></i></th>
   <thead>
 </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To patch the issue, you can move the `<i>` tags to before the actual text in `<th>`. That should improve your alignment issues by a lot.

To completely fix it though, you may need to set the `vertical-align:top;` on those `<th>`.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/JgSMq/2/) is an example.

Answer (score 1):

Well maybe you can try something like:

```
th {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Here is your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/JgSMq/1/